# JSF primefaces email functionality with both send and receive feature

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I wanted to develop an application using prime faces for sending email to customer as well as admin can see the emails with image attached details etc.

Is there any existing components supports email in JSF and primefaces using commons email or other api??

Comment: Java EE compliant servers handle email sending services as resources. You can learn them from Oracle's Java EE documentation. Here is an example from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javamail/javamail.html

Comment: You can use SendGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces wouldn't solve email client problem

It can provide components to build interfaces that interacts with backend API

For instance, to actually send email message you in addition to Primefaces components you can easily integrate Gmail JAVA API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java